# Создание ссылки в Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование

Как сделать чтобы Node возвратил страницу со ссылкой, на которую можно кликнуть?

```js
res.send('Документ создан. Вы можете загрузить его здесь - http://localhost:1337/download');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кликабельная ссылка - это уже HTML. То есть, Вам надо вернуть не просто текстовую строку, а что-то в таком духе:

```
res.send('<html><body>Документ создан. Вы можете загрузить его <a href="http://localhost:1337/download">здесь</a></body></html>');
```